# Solution for WebRTC mediaserver

Tags: c#, node.js, webrtc

I would like to consultate what is the best solution for mediastream server(WebRTC) that can fulfill my needs.

What I need:

- Easily manage 50+ connections. Ability to switch who is hearing whom, and who is talking to whom.
- Clients should have only one WebRTC connection. Which is going to server. Server then again, control what he is hearing, and to whom he is talking to..

That is basically my needs. I prefer languages like C# and NodeJS. 
I looked at kurento, which seems to have kinda bad documentation, and it uses Java which I am not familiar with.

Any alternatives, suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Kurento has both Java and NodeJS libraries.  The core media server is written in Java and C, but you'll probably never need to touch or read that code.

Comment: You can also check out Red5, it doesn't support WebRTC in basic community version, but it is a media server, if you purchase the Red5 pro you can get the WebRTC support in it.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point about webRTC is that it's peer to peer, and doesn't need a server (except for the initial signalling).

The beauty of this is that you can scale to handle as many connections as you like. The performance is only limited by the client browsers and their connection speed.

You only need a media server if you need to do video conferencing for more than one or two users on the same call.

Writing a video conferencing server is a big deal, it's a complex problem to solve, and I would recommend starting with an existing open source project as your base. If you go down this path, you will need some serious hardware and bandwidth, because the server will be handling each and every video stream, and need to be scalable.

This article lists 6 open source projects that may fit your needs: https://elearningindustry.com/top-6-open-source-web-conferencing-software-tools-elearning-professionals

> **Top Open Source Web Conferencing Software Tools eLearning
>   Professionals Should Know About**
>
> While there are plenty of open source web conferencing tools available
>   these days, there are also a number of budget-friendly alternatives
>   that still offer the same features and functions. In fact, open source
>   web conferencing software offers you the opportunity to host virtual
>   training events, collaborate with colleagues, and offer learners
>   personalized support without paying hefty monthly fees.